# How to encode username and password?

Tags: android, encode, urlencode

I need to send encoded username and Password through request body. 
Here I'm sending username and password in the format of JSON object.

How to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Thanks in advance.`. No. We want thank after you have been helped.

Comment: At last I found a solution. Actually Base64 class is not available in Android, so you need to add this Base64 class in your project. [Here is a link](http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html) for further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

**Encode**

```
String encodedUsername = URLEncoder.encode(username);
String encodedPassword = URLEncoder.encode(password);
```

**Decode**

```
String decodedUsername = URLDecoder.decode(encodedUsername);
String decodedPassword = URLDecoder.decode(encodedPassword);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search would've done the trick...

> URLEncoder should be the way to go. You only need to keep in mind to
>   encode only the individual query string parameter name and/or value,
>   not the entire URL, for sure not the query string parameter separator
>   character `&` nor the parameter name-value separator character `=`.
>
> ```
> String q = "random word £500 bank $";
> String url = "http://example.com/query?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(q, "UTF-8");
> ```
>
> ...

Source: 
[Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)